# Swift NSWorkspace Open Link with Finder, Hide Finder Window

Tags: swift, appkit, finder, nsworkspace

With NSWorkspace one can open an URL in Finder.
If it is a network drive, it will also mount the Link in `Volumes`

**How can one open the URL in Finder without actually popping up a Finder Window in foreground?**

The code below does not hide the popup

```swift
let validUrl = URL(string: "smb://server/folder")
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.hides = true // seems to do nothing...
NSWorkspace.shared.open(validUrl, configuration: configuration) { _, error in
    // Finder Window in Popup occurs
}
```

Comment: The `OpenConfiguration` object is for launching apps. It has no effect while mounting a volume. To mount shared volumes silently use `NetFSMountURLAsync` of the `NetFS` framework. It's pretty old but it works even in Monterey.